# Counting BST leves on C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

There was a recursive way to count levels, this is similar but it doesn't work. Which is my mistake?

```
struct s_node
{
  struct s_node * left;
  struct s_node * right;
  int value;
}
typedef struct s_node * t_node;
int levels (t_node tree)
{
  if(tree != NULL)
  {
    return 1+levels(tree->left)+levels(tree->right);
  }
  else
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, enable compiler warnings, this shouldn't compile. What do they tell you?

Comment: This still does not compile. Why don't you copy/paste your *real* code? And what does "it doesn't work" mean? What result do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: why it does not compile? well, if i have a bst of 2 levels, i want this to show 2, but what it shows is 3..of course there is a main..this is just the function

Comment: *"... apart from two ; missing ..."* - Well, that's what I meant. I just makes me suspicious if not the real code is copy/pasted.

Answer (score 0):

This counts the total number of nodes. If you want to "count the levels", which I'm assuming means you want to determine the height of the tree, you would modify your code to something like this:

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    return b;
}

int levels (struct s_node * tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        return 1 + max(levels(tree->left), levels(tree->right));
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Note that there may still be C errors in there, I haven't used C in many years now, but you should get the algorithm idea.

Comment: I did mention I haven't used C in a long time now so I don't know. My answer was not directed at his syntax, but at his algorithm. You seem to know more C details than I do so if something doesn't look right feel free to edit my answer rather than downvote it. It would be of more help to the op.

Comment: Given the latest comments of the OP you were probably on the right track. I have taken the liberty to edit your answer and fix the pointer stuff (hoping that I did not make an error myself).

Comment: Is there any other way without having to go to max? Just in one function and with the structure i've described?

Comment: I don't know of a way without determining which subtree is higher. But you could do this instead of using the max function (the code formatting will be gone):

int levels (struct s_node * tree)
{
 int left_height, right_height;
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
  left_height = levels(tree->left);
  right_height = levels(tree->right);
        return 1 + (left_height > right_height ? left_height : right_height);
    }
    else 
        return 0;
}